# How are local constant variables treated in C programming

Tags: c

I've been messing around with Rust and the immutable variable idea is interesting to me.
so I've been using it in my C programs as well. But now I'm wondering if there is any difference in a local variable that is defined with the "const" keyword and one that isn't.

I assume both are still put on the stack so there is no difference? other than the fact that it cannot be modified after declared and initialized obviously.

Comment: If you don't take the address of a constant variable whose value can be calculated at compile-time, the *as-if rule* allows the compiler to substitute the use of the constant variable with the value itself. That's not possible for run-time constants, whose value are only known when running the program (for example constant function arguments).

Comment: The `const` keyword means read-only, and those local variables are put at the same location than non const one, you can move the const away with a cast, so it's Just an hint for the programmers, there's no real enforcement, not a language construct as you May know from rust. Things might be different for global variables. But I might be wrong, that's Just how I remember it. But compilers May take the const for granted, and casting away May lead to undefined behavior, Compiler replacing global const with actual value known at compile-time.

Comment: The compiler is allowed to optimize local variables any way it wants to. In practice it treats const and non-const the same, since it *knows* whether you edit the variable, unless you take its address.

Comment: For most part `const` on local variable is to convey intent to the _programmer_, and prevent the _programmer_ from creating bugs by modifying wrong variables. Compiler is quite capable of seeing if a local variable is never modified, and treating it as a constant value even without `const`.

Comment: @user253751, the compiler's treatment of `const` variables does not have to be the same, and in practice, the compiler is likely at least to produce warnings about violations of `const`-correctness, which is a difference.  It might go further by, say, performing optimizations that it can prove correct only by relying on `const` objects to not be modified, which can arise if the object's address is passed to another function.

Comment: @Tim.  Note: There are constant _objects_.  There are no constant _variables_.  `const` is similar to _constant_ , but not the same.  Sounds like you are talking about `const` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume both are still put on the stack so there is no difference? other than the fact that it cannot be modified after declared and initialized obviously.

In general, it's not safe to assume that *either* will be assigned storage on the stack, but indeed, `const` is not a discriminator in that regard.

The primary effect of `const` is to signal programmer intent and provide for the compiler to recognize violations of that intent.

For local variables whose addresses are never exposed outside the innermost block in which they are declared, that's about the extent of it, provided that the program indeed does not violate that intent.  For such objects, the compiler does not need help from `const` to recognize or make use of their unchangingness.

On the other hand, where the address of a `const` object *is* exposed outside the scope in which that object is declared, `const`-correctly, the compiler may rely on the object indeed not being modified via that address or another derived from it.  For example, that could make some optimizations possible that would not otherwise be safe.

Overall, I guess the take-home is that `const` does not convey a difference in form, but rather one in allowable function.  The compiler may produce different messages and different binaries for sources that are the same but for one or more appearances of `const` -- but it also might *not*.  It depends on the compiler and the (other) details of the code.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume both are still put on the stack so there is no difference?

The only real difference is that if you attempt to modify the variable you'll get a compile time error if it was `const` (which can be helpful, especially for "maintenance coders", or a future version of you that forgot your original code's details)

If you don't modify it; then a modern compiler will auto-detect that it's not modified and optimize the code without caring if it was/wasn't `const` (likely including the complete removal of the variable).